# Timeouts with ghc 7.8.3

Tags: haskell, ghc

I am currently trying to compile a simulator created with ghc 7.6.3 with the new ghc 7.8.3 and came across an issue with GHC.Event.

I use the timeout functions, which have changed with 7.8.3. For 7.8.3 there is now a global `getSystemTimerManager` function which returns a `TimerManager`. But the `TimerManager` data type is not exported, it is part of the hidden package GHC.Event.TimerManager. When I try to import this module I get:

```
Utils/Timer.hs:16:8:
    Could not find module ‘GHC.Event.TimerManager’
    it is a hidden module in the package ‘base’
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

What is the reason, that this module is hidden, so that the timer functions can not be used?

Comment: Are you using `cabal` to build? You may need to add `base` to your `build-depends` section of your cabal file.

Comment: You aren't supposed to have access to `TimerManager`, it's like the `IO` type, it's hidden to prevent abuse.  Instead, `GHC.Event` exports `registerTimeout`, `unregisterTimeout`, and `updateTimeout` for performing timeout operations.

Comment: @JustinWood Adding `base` to `build-depends` won't fix this, the `GHC.Event.TimerManager` module is hidden, meaning it isn't exported by `base` at all.  GHC has intentionally made this module inaccessible to prevent misuse of its contents.

Comment: @bheklilr: regardless, I think not exporting the `TimerManager` type was a mistake.  There's no way having access to the type constructor would allow anyone to misuse the implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the type isn't exported, all that means is that you don't get to write down a type signature that mentions the ThreadManager.  You can still call `registerTimeout`, `updateTimeout`, or `unregisterTimeout`.

Example:

```
module Main where

import GHC.Event
import Control.Concurrent (threadDelay)

main = do
  tm <- getSystemTimerManager
  _ <- registerTimeout tm 100000 $ do
    putStrLn "timeout!"
  putStrLn "sleeping"
  threadDelay 200000
  putStrLn "wokeup"
```

This compiles and runs and prints `"sleeping\ntimeout!\nwokeup"`.

What wouldn't work would be to try to write down the type of tm.  That can occasionally be annoying if you wanted to stick the timer manager in some data structure.  But I guess you're not supposed to do that.

Comment: Ah, ok I see. Ok, then I need to redesign a bit... Thanks!